# How to read <input type="hidden"...> in JavaScript on subsequent page?

Tags: javascript

One first page: 
A form SUBMIT goes to a subsequent page.

VBscript can see the hidden value with ... Request("myName") ...

How do I do the same thing in JavaScript.

```
 alert(window.location.search);
```

or

```
 alert(window.top.location.search.substring(1));
```

return nothing.

Comment: You're getting data sent in *POST* method with *client-side* VBScript?

Comment: Like you would do for any other _POST_ variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you dont. When you submit a form it sends the values to a server, and the "server-side" reads that in vbscript as Request (Requested). If you want to let the requested value accessible to the Javascript, your server-side (subsequent) page must write that Request data back to the client-side, in other worlds, you have to write the requested value directily in the HTML that will be send back to the client browser.

Ex: In your ASP (Server-Side Subsequent VBScript file) you should write

```
Response.Write ("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert('" & Request("Data") & "')</script>")
```

Comment: I agree with you. But I don't know about that Response.Write.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='hidden' id='hiddenId'/>
```

jQuery:

```
var value = $('#hiddenId').val();
alert(value);
```

Or

```
var value = document.getElementById('hiddenId').value;
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you have to have the method set to GET.

```
<form method="GET" action="somepage">
  <input type=hidden name=myHiddenValue />
</form>
```

Then on the next page, you can parse the search part of the url with a function like this.

```
function parseSearch(search, key) {
    search = search.substring(1), items=search.split("&");
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i], parts = item.split("=");
        if (parts[0] === key) {
            return parts[1] || true;
        }
    }
}
```

```
parseSearch(location.search, "myHiddenValue"); // returns the hidden value
```

### [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ukGDr/)

Comment: Assuming it is a Form and is also a hidden field, for security reasons I will strongly not recommend this kind of solution, I also reinforce to not use such approach once @JoeHall have a server-side VBScript access (not client-side only)

Comment: @Roger, yeah there are definitely better solutions, and I should have mentioned that.  This is the only way to do it with JavaScript only.